# Make each "image" of a Ratingbar clickable

Tags: android, ratingbar

I'm using `RatingBar` as an indicator. [This is an indicator of progress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PWqiZ.jpg).

Now I want each of those blue pentagons clickable because I want to pass a value that is unique to each "image" to a next activity.

When I tried `OnTouchListener` it only applies for the whole `RatingBar`.

Answer (score 0):

You could get the value of the rating bar and use a switch case to the value you want

```
RatingBar ratingBar = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.ir.yourRatingBarId);

switch (ratingBar.getRating()) {
    case "the value you need":
        do something
        break;
    case "another value":
        do something else
        break;
}
```

Comment: Please indent code with four spaces to enable syntax highlighting. This time, I have done it for you :) This page might be interesting: [Markdown help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: yeah but how do I make each "image" clickable?